# boolean in GUI returns NPE?

Tags: java, boolean

Here is the code:

```
    final JRadioButton banking = new JRadioButton("Enable Banking");
banking.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
    fish.useBank = banking.isSelected() ? true : false;
    if(banking.isSelected()) {
        scroll2.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        scroll2.setEnabled(false);
    }
    }
});
```

fish is a reference to the main class, where there is just a simple boolean

```
public boolean useBank;
```

for some reason it always returns with an NPE when I try to use it in other classes. I'm kind of new to Java so any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How is fish set and declared for this function?

Comment: How is `fish` assigned?

Comment: Edit: you guys were right! I forgot to pass it in the other class's parameter. Thanks :)